# How to list duplicate nodes, with views, based on compared fields with links

Tags: 7, nodes, views

I'm trying to create a list with duplicate nodes, so i can delete those.
I'm not coder and I have already tried the module "remove duplicates" without success, so i have to use views with vbo module.

The field i have to compare nodes, contains a link.
If the same link is in more than one node, i need it to be listed.

I have turned aggreation on.
I have one field, displaying a link.
I have created a filter, pointing at the above field with link,  with "count" and set it to "show only greater than 1" acording to other similar questions on how to list duplicate  titles.

Unfortunately this does nothing for me. As soon as i turn on the filter, there is no output.

Can you tell me what I'm missing here ?
Sorry for the poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Create content field of the fields i want to aggregate.
Create Content NID and set to COUNT.
Create filter Content NID with Is greater than 1.

Voila
Also the field with the data is to be aggregate, must NOT be a link, then it wont work.

Comment: When I do this as you indicate here, I indeed get a list of nodes that share the same field. However, how to bulk delete the duplicates? If i turn on views bulk operations, the view displays no results any more. How did you manage to bulk delete the duplciates?

Comment: Sorry, i did not see your question, before now.
I never did figure out how to actually delete the nodes.
I tried several times, but as you mention, without luck, so i gave up for the time.
If you figure this out, i would be very very happy to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an easy, non-coder based way to do that with views. You *could* however create a view with the link field visible, and as a sort parameter as well. That way identical field values would show up next to one another. It'd be then the process of selecting the duplicate node (I'd suggest deleting the one with the higher nid) and deleting it.

Let me know if that makes any sense at all, or if you need a 5 minute proof of concept demo.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not an option for me as i have over 200000 nodes and thousands of duplicates. I would never finish manually :)

Answer (score 1):

Create a view that is a table. Add the required fields to that view including the link field. Click settings here: "Format: Table | Settings"

Then group by the field for the link.

Like so: [image]

Here is an example: [image]

Comment: Thanks.
This is what i already have done, just using fields instead of table.
But the table do give some better layout.

The duplicated entries is shown fine together.

But the problem still remains. How do i use the count funktion ?
I still need to figure out how to aggregate the duplicates and use the filter funktion to show only duplicates with >1